# Google Sheets Apps Script 'Unknown Function'

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-maps-api-3, custom-function

I created a script in Google Sheets Apps Script to call the Google Maps API, but the function is not recognized in the spreadsheet:

[image: unknown function in spreadsheet]

Below is the code I am using:

```
function mapAddress(input) {
 var API_KEY = 'XXXXXXX';
 var url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?query=' +
 input + '&key=' + API_KEY;
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
 var json = response.getContentText();
 obj = JSON.parse(json);
 addr = obj.formatted_address;
 return addr;
 }
```

I am using Chrome on Mac OS 11.6

I was expecting I'd be able to use a custom function in my spreadsheet, but when I try to use it, it returns a blank value.

Comment: Did you click the deploy button in App Scripts editor?

Comment: I did, as a web app

Comment: Try as a library

Comment: I just did, still seeing the same issue

Comment: Weird. Hard refresh the sheet and try it. Also, when you go to Deploy > Manage, do you see it there?

Comment: Regarding the `Unknown function` message, you have to [include the `@customfunction` tag](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) (The function should still work even without it). Regarding the blank return, please try to log the variables, i.e. `console.log(obj)`.